# Do shastras sanction displaying idols of Hindu Gods as landscaping?

Tags: shiva, temple, agamas, idols

[This Tripadvisor link](https://www.tripadvisor.in/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g303878-d2634686-i89940087-Shree_Swaminarayan_Temple_Bhuj-Bhuj_Kutch_District_Gujarat.html) shows idols of Lord Shiva & Goddess Parvati used as landscaping at a Swaminarayan Temple.

[image] 
<sub>(This photo of Shree Swaminarayan Temple Bhuj is courtesy of TripAdvisor)</sub>

A revered God to hundreds of millions of Hindus has been put out there in the elements to be defecated on by pigeons.

Shouldn't idols of Gods be kept inside temple premises?

Surely, Agama shastras have something to say about this.

Comment: What is degrading in it? I can't find anything.

Comment: nothing degrading.

Comment: I want what agama shastras say about it and not personal opinions @Swami Vishwananda

Comment: You need to expand on the question, one-liner questions with links are confusing.

Comment: There are so many such [magnificent statues of Lord Shiva](http://www.walkthroughindia.com/walkthroughs/top-10-tallest-lord-shiva-statues-in-india/)

Comment: "There are so many such magnificent statues of Lord Shiva" not as landscaping decor of a covered temple.

Comment: Har ki paudi @S K